# Binary search implemention ( mostly code structure problems, aka newbie problems)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have just learned my very first steps in C (I used to code in python) and as a such I'm facing great difficulty with the syntax, and as well as with binary search implementation. (I'm new to programming.)

So here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 1000

int binary_search(int array[size], int givenNumber) {
  do {
    int start = 0;
    int end = size;
    int middle = start + end / 2;
    int left = size - 1;
    int right = size + 1;

    if (array[middle] == givenNumber) {
      printf("location: %d, number: %i", middle, givenNumber);
      return middle;
    } else if (array[left] < givenNumber) {

      int start = 0;
      int end = array[left];
      int middle = start + end / 2;
      return middle;
    } else if (array[right] > middle) {

      int start = array[right];
      int end = size;
      int middle = start + end / 2;
      return middle;
    } else {
      return -1;
      break;
    }
  }
  } while (int middle != givenNumber)

int main() {
  int sorted_array[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sorted_array[i] = i;
  }
  return binary_search(sorted_array, 349);
}
```

My problems are:

1 - when compiling, the error is something along the lines of "in while block "middle" isn't defined"

I have no clue on why the value isn't passing from the do block to the while block. Note that I added "return middle" to each if / else-if block, as I I thought it **may** help.

2- I'm not even quite sure if my **own** implementation of this binary search is correct. I have looked up how to implement it but I found it next to impossible to read the syntax, this is just to give a heads up.

**UPDATE**:
I have reconstructed the whole code according to the notes users have given in the answers below, and well, my algorithm is working and now it could find any number in any given array, however I'm unable to figure out a way to tell if the array doesn't have that `givenNumber` as it would get eventually stuck.

Here's an input/output:
`int array[size] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,14,24,53,100};`

function:  `binary_search(array, 24);`

output: `Location: 11, Number: 24`

Which is pretty good, however if I enter a number which doesn't exist in the array, the loop continues to search endlessly (gets stuck in recursion)

```
here's the updated code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 14
int start = 0;
int end = size -1;
int middle;
int left;
int right;
int binary_search(int array[size], int givenValue)
{

    middle = (start + end) / 2;
    printf("\nstart: %d \nend: %d \nmiddle: %d \n\n",start, end, middle);

    do
    {
        if (start > end)
        {
            printf("item isn't found");
            break;
            return -1;
        }
        middle = (start+end)/2;
        left =  middle -1;
        right = middle +1;
        if (array[middle] ==  givenValue)
        {
            printf("Location: %d, Number: %d", middle, givenValue);
            return middle;
            break;
        }
        if(array[middle] > givenValue)
        {
            end = right;
            return binary_search(array, givenValue);
        }
        if(array[middle] < givenValue)
        {
            start = left;
            return binary_search(array, givenValue);
        }

    }
    while (start <= end);
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[size] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,14,24,53,100};
    return binary_search(array, 24);
}
```

My condition is that if `start` is greater than `end` then the item doesn't exist, and it doesn't work at all because `left/right` keeps getting stuck at the same values (Run the code to know what I mean)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The scope of `middle` is inside the `do-while`, you need to declare it outside of the the loop for it to be used in the while test.

Comment: but in that case how would I constantly alter it so I'd find the `givenNumber`?

Comment: Cut and paste in the true code.

Comment: Review `int middle = start + end / 2;`  It OK when `start == 0`.

Comment: You need to understand what a variable declaration is. You only say `int middle;` when you declare the variable, which in this case should be in the outer scope or `binary_search`.  Every time after that you need to omit the `int` since the variable has already been declared.  Read up on this.

Comment: So from what you've just said it means that in the given block whether it's while or do or whatever, you only need to declare it once, and later use it normally. Okay, I will read, thanks.

Comment: I pasted the original code from the compiler without any edits, though.

Comment: I would recommend unaccepting the answer you accepted. That code has a huge amount of flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

1. The loop does *not* iterate. All parts of `if/else` have a `return`
2. *massive* amount of "shadowing" of variables
3. size is *invariant* so left/right are *always* set to the same thing
4. `left` and `right` should be started at `0` and `size - 1` respectively
5. variables are used *inconsistently* (e.g. `start` is both an array index and an array *value*)
6. The function is more complex than it needs to be and has some extraneous variables
7. Your binary search algorithm is suspect

First and foremost, I'd recommend removing all "sub-scoped" variable declarations that shadow outer scoped ones (i.e. put all variables at the outermost scope).

Do this until you're more comfortable with these declarations. Learn more about the difference between:

1. variable declaration: `int x;`
2. variable declaration with initializer: `int x = 5;`
3. variable assignment: `x = 5;`

---

I've annotated your original function, created a test/diagnostic function and created a refactored function that passes the diagnostic test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 1000

int
binary_fixed(int *array, int givenNumber)
{
    int left;
    int right;
    int middle;
    int curval;
    int retindex = -1;

    left = 0;
    right = size - 1;

    while (left <= right) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        curval = array[middle];

        if (curval == givenNumber) {
            retindex = middle;
            break;
        }

        if (curval > givenNumber)
            right = middle - 1;
        else
            left = middle + 1;
    }

    return retindex;
}

int
binary_search(int *array, int givenNumber)
{
    int middle;

    // NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ iterate
    // NOTE/BUG: _massive_ amount of "shadowing" of variables
    // NOTE/BUG: size is _invariant_ so left/right are _always_ set to the
    // same thing
    // NOTE/BUG: left and right should start at 0 and size - 1 respectively
    // NOTE/BUG: variables are used _inconsistently_ (e.g. start is both
    // an array index and an array _value_)
    do {
        int start = 0;
        int end = size;
        int middle = start + end / 2;
        int left = size - 1;
        int right = size + 1;

        if (array[middle] == givenNumber) {
            printf("location: %d, number: %i\n", middle, givenNumber);
            return middle;
        }
        else if (array[left] < givenNumber) {

            int start = 0;
            int end = array[left];
            int middle = start + end / 2;

            return middle;
        }
        else if (array[right] > middle) {

            int start = array[right];
            int end = size;
            int middle = start + end / 2;

            return middle;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    } while (middle != givenNumber);

    printf("BADRETURN givenNumber=%d\n", givenNumber);
}

int sorted_array[size];

void
test(const char *who,int (*fnc)(int *,int))
{
    int i;
    int r;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        r = fnc(sorted_array, i);

        if (r != i) {
            printf("ERROR -- EXPECTED: %d ACTUAL: %d (from %s)\n", i, r, who);
            // break;
        }
    }
}

int
main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sorted_array[i] = i;
    }

    //test("ORIGINAL",binary_search);
    test("FIXED",binary_fixed);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since you're coming from `python`, here are a few points that may help with your understanding.

Arrays are passed to functions as *pointers*, so in the function argument list, `int *array` is equivalent. Doing `int array[size]` is an advanced technique. Avoid it for now. In C, you can't do `array.count` as you can in python. So, for now, pass the count as an additional argument.

Pointers are something that python doesn't have, so you'll have to learn about how to use them. Once you get the hang of them, they are quite powerful and can make code run quite fast.

In C [and most languages *except* python [and php]], the default scope is *global*. It's the reverse of python. In python, unless you specify `global x`, then `x` is private to the function. In other languages, to have `x` be local to the function, you have to declare it at function scope.

In C, *all* variables *must* be declared *somewhere*: global scope, function scope [or a block scope within a function], or as an argument. And, each declaration must specify an explicit type. There is no equivalent of javascript's declaration of `var x`. After that, `x` could be either a string or a value depending upon what you set it to: (e.g. `x = 23` or `x = "abc"`)

In C, `x` must be given a type such as: `int x;` or `double x;` or `int *x;` or `char *x`.

---

Here is your revised code with annotations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// NOTE: this is hardwired
#define size 14

// NOTE: this is _global_ scope -- while not absolutely wrong, using function
// scope below is faster/better and provides better isolation -- this doesn't
// scale as well
int start = 0;
int end = size - 1;
int middle;
int left;
int right;

// NOTE: in C, using "int *array" is equivalent [and in many cases preferred]
// NOTE: the array count should be passed in as a separate argument
int
binary_search(int array[size], int givenValue)
{
    // NOTE: this is _function_ scope

    // NOTE: this calc of middle is extraneous because it is recalculated
    // below
    middle = (start + end) / 2;
    printf("\nstart: %d \nend: %d \nmiddle: %d \n\n", start, end, middle);

    // NOTE/BUG: this function combines _both_ a loop implementation and a
    // recursive implementation -- we have to pick one or the other as trying
    // to do both messes things us -- the recursion is broken [see below]

    // NOTE: this loop checks start vs end _twice_ in the loop -- it only
    // needs to check in one place -- convert this to "while (start <= end) {"
    // instead of a "do {...} while (whatever);" loop [which is usually not
    // as good]
    do {
        if (start > end) {
            printf("item isn't found");
            break;

            // NOTE/BUG: this return will _never_ be executed because we
            // break out of the loop and what is worse we'll return an
            // unknown/undefined value because
            return -1;
        }

        middle = (start + end) / 2;

        // NOTE/BUG: these are reversed
        left = middle - 1;
        right = middle + 1;

        if (array[middle] == givenValue) {
            printf("Location: %d, Number: %d", middle, givenValue);
            return middle;
            break;
        }

        // NOTE/BUG: these recursive calls do nothing because they do _not_
        // further limit the scope and cause infinite recursion -- to make
        // a recursive version work, start/end would need to be arguments:
        //   return binary_search(array,givenValue,start,end)
        // and we shouldn't loop -- the recursive calls just aren't needed

        // NOTE/BUG: the tests here are broken -- they are the reverse of
        // the correct ones

        if (array[middle] > givenValue) {
            end = right;
            return binary_search(array, givenValue);
        }

        if (array[middle] < givenValue) {
            start = left;
            return binary_search(array, givenValue);
        }

        // NOTE/BUG: this extra test is extraneous and would be done too late
        // if the array size was zero -- a case that isn't handled here
    } while (start <= end);

    // NOTE/BUG: when we break out of the loop, we need to return _some_ value
    // here -- this would be flagged by the compiler using the -Wall option
}

int
main(void)
{
    int array[size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 24, 53, 100 };

    // NOTE/BUG: the return value from main can only handle numbers 0-255
    // better to print the return value
    return binary_search(array, 24);
}
```

---

Here is a working version of your revised code.

The loop is now a simple `while`. The function takes a *separate* count argument. It loops instead of recurses. The reversed `if` logic has been fixed. Again, a diagnostic test has been added.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
binary_search(int *array, int size, int givenValue)
{
    // NOTE: this is _function_ scope
    int start = 0;
    int end = size - 1;
    int middle;
    int left;
    int right;
    int match_index;

    // assume failure
    match_index = -1;

    // NOTE: this calc of middle is extraneous because it is recalculated
    // below
    middle = (start + end) / 2;
    printf("\nstart: %d \nend: %d \nmiddle: %d \n\n", start, end, middle);

    while (start <= end) {
        middle = (start + end) / 2;
        left = middle - 1;
        right = middle + 1;

        if (array[middle] == givenValue) {
            printf("Location: %d, Number: %d\n", middle, givenValue);
            match_index = middle;
            break;
        }

        if (array[middle] > givenValue) {
            end = left;
        }

        if (array[middle] < givenValue) {
            start = right;
        }
    }

    if (match_index < 0)
        printf("match not found -- givenValue=%d\n",givenValue);

    return match_index;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 24, 53, 100 };
    int count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int curidx;
    int valwant;
    int match;

    printf("%d\n",binary_search(array, count, 24));

    // run diagnostic on all values
    for (curidx = 0;  curidx < count;  ++curidx) {
        // get value to search for
        valwant = array[curidx];

        match = binary_search(array,count,valwant);

        if (match != curidx) {
            printf("fault: curidx=%d valwant=%d match=%d\n",
                curidx,valwant,match);
        }
    }

    // test lower range failure
    valwant = array[0] - 1;
    match = binary_search(array,count,valwant);
    if (match >= 0)
        printf("fault: valwant=%d match=%d\n",valwant,match);

    // test upper range failure
    valwant = array[count - 1] + 1;
    match = binary_search(array,count,valwant);
    if (match >= 0)
        printf("fault: valwant=%d match=%d\n",valwant,match);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your notes, it directed me into the right path. I have updated the code, please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

A typical binary search implementation would either loop or recurse until the number is found.  The naive recursive code is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 1000

int binary_search(int array[size], int givenNumber, int start, int end) {
    int middle;
    middle = (start + end) / 2;

    if (start > end)
        return -1;

    if (array[middle] == givenNumber) {
        printf("location: %d, number: %i", middle, givenNumber);
        return middle;
    } else if (array[middle] < givenNumber) {
        return binary_search(array, givenNumber, middle + 1, end);
    } else { // if (array[middle] > givenNumber)
        return binary_search(array, givenNumber, start, middle - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int sorted_array[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            sorted_array[i] = i * 2;
    }
    if (binary_search(sorted_array, 349, 0, size - 1) < 0) {
        printf("value not found\n");
    }
    if (binary_search(sorted_array, 34, 0, size - 1) < 0) {
        printf("value not found\n");
    }
}
```

Notice in the recursion we call binary_search each time with a new start and end range based on the sorted array and the provided input in `givenNumber`.

Answer (score -2):

1. You can't declare a variable inside a while statement. Move it to the top of your function.
2. You have a misplaced curly brace in your code.

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 1000

int binary_search(int array[size], int givenNumber) {
  int middle;
  do {
    int start = 0;
    int end = size;
    int middle = start + end / 2;
    int left = size - 1;
    int right = size + 1;

    if (array[middle] == givenNumber) {
      printf("location: %d, number: %i", middle, givenNumber);
      return middle;
    } else if (array[left] < givenNumber) {

      int start = 0;
      int end = array[left];
      int middle = start + end / 2;
      return middle;
    } else if (array[right] > middle) {

      int start = array[right];
      int end = size;
      int middle = start + end / 2;
      return middle;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  } while (middle != givenNumber);
}

int main() {
  int sorted_array[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sorted_array[i] = i;
  }
  return binary_search(sorted_array, 349);
}
```

Comment: There's no way this could work.  You are shadowing `middle` all over the place in this code.

Comment: It worked as in just a code, but practically, the code is useless.

Comment: The loop _always_ returns on the _first_ iteration (i.e. all four of the `if/else` clauses have a `return`)